# How to find script language

Tags: scripting

I'm pretty new at writing scripts, so I hope I wont sound ridiculously :).

I'm trying to find the language in which this script is written.
Аny help is appreciated.

```
SetVar(Hlp, Get("Datachannel", "State"))
if (OR(StrCmp(GetVar(Hlp), "1"),StrCmp(GetVar(Hlp), "3")))
{
}
else
{
 SetVar(DCType, Get("Datachannel", "Type"))
if (StrMCmp (GetVar(DCType), "*MET")) 

{
 if( Cmp( StrFind(GetVar(DCField), GetVar(IsInDCField)), "==", "-1") )
 {
    SetVar(RoutDcount, "0")
    SetVar(C82Open, "0")
 }
}
}
```

Comment: Still needs more context. File ending is .sct, you say. What's the rest of the name? Where does it come from? Operating System?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like C, which is not a scripting language but a proper, compiled programming language. The function names `STrMCmp` don't really match any standard library that google would know, so this is hard to tell.

Comment: This code is from a script file .sct, so I'm sure i'ts scripting language, but I don't know which one

Comment: Well, add that information to your original question, to attract more answers. What does the script do? with which software did it come?